# Cant initialize array error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'initializer-list' to 'abd'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Hi I have something like:

```
enum abd {a,b,c};

class d { 
  private: 
    abd tab[3][3]; 
  public: 
    d() { 
      tab[3][3] = { {a,a,a}, {a,a,a}, {a,a,a} }; 
    } 
}
```

and it yells:

> error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'initializer-list' to 'abd' and 
>   IntelliSense: too many initializer values.

I'm probably blind, cause I cant find my mistake so please tell me whats wrong and how to repair it.

Comment: You're accessing the array out of bounds. Keep in mind built-in arrays are not assignable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays have no assignment operators. You could write instead

```
class d { 
  private: 
    abd tab[3][3] = { {a,a,a}, {a,a,a}, {a,a,a} }; 
  public: 
    d() { 
    } 
};
```

If the compiler does not support this feature then use some standard algorithm as for example `std::fill` to assign values to the elements of the array.

For example

```
#include <algorithm>

enum abd  { a, b, d };

    class d { 
      private: 
        abd tab[3][3]; 
      public: 
        d() {
            std::fill( reinterpret_cast<abd *>( tab ), 
                       reinterpret_cast<abd *>( tab ) + 9,
                       a );         
        } 
    };
i
```

Comment: What if in-class initialization isn't supported?

Comment: @0x499602D2  In this case you can use some standard algorithm as for example std::fill to set values of the array.

Comment: Problem is that this leads to error C2536: cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays.

Answer (score 2):

```
class d { 
  private: 
    abd tab[3][3]; 
  public: 
    d() : tab { {a,a,a}, {a,a,a}, {a,a,a}} {} 
};
```

**Update**

It seems that using

```
    d() : tab { {a,a,a}, {a,a,a}, {a,a,a}} {}
```

is a problem in VS 2013. See [the bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/792161/constructor-initializer-list-does-not-support-braced-init-list-form).

Without support for that, the only choice I can think of is using nested `for` loops to initialize `tab`:

```
d()
{
   for ( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
      for ( int j = 0; j < 3; ++j )
         tab[i][j] = a;
}
```

Comment: What does one do pre-C++11?

Comment: Problem is that this leads to error C2536: cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays.

Comment: @R Sahu thanks I choose Vlads answer for std::fill but you are right too(and with VS2013 being a problem too :) )

Answer (score 2):

This thing `{ {a,a,a}, {a,a,a}, {a,a,a} }` called *initializer list* because you can use it only at *initialization* of array.

```
abd tab[3][3] = { {a,a,a}, {a,a,a}, {a,a,a} };
```